# Setting an attribute in mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I am trying to set the attribute flag to false like this:

```
Model.where(:s_id => s_id).flag = false
```

(I have s_id) but it didn't work
and this one didn't work too :

```
Model.find(s_id).flag = false
```

Any help??

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that you've changed the `flag` attribute, but not saved the document afterwards. There's lots of different ways you can handle this, most of which are detailed in the [persistence section of the documentation](http://mongoid.org/docs/persistence.html).

If you're only updating one model, and you have the ID, you can use the `update_attribute` method:

```
Model.find(id).update_attribute(:flag, false)
```

The `update_attribute` method updates the attribute (obviously) but then also calls `save` on the document, persisting the changes in the database. You could achieve this the long way by doing:

```
m = Model.find(id)
m.flag = false
m.save
```

Alternatively, if you're wanting to update a set of models, from a criteria (like the `where` method), you can use `update_all`:

```
Model.where(:flag => true).update_all(:flag => false)
```